# How do I parse json array using .each with no outer name?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I want to parse this json using jquery and each with a loop. I have only seen json examples where it is wrapped in array with a title such as results. How do I parse json like below...?

```
$.each(json.results, function() {
    console.log(this['title']);
});
```

```
[{"title":"About Us","url_title":"about_us","entry_id":"155","channel_id":"2","author_id":"1","status":"open","entry_date":"1287508538","edit_date":"20101209122240","expiration_date":"0","about_body":"We are the greatest.","about_image":"","about_staff_title":"Joe","about_extended":"More about us.","color":"d12626"},{"title":"Contact Us","url_title":"contact_us","entry_id":"223","channel_id":"2","author_id":"1","status":"open","entry_date":"1291918929","edit_date":"20101209122310","expiration_date":"0","about_body":"Email us.","about_image":"","about_staff_title":"Bob","about_extended":"","color":"080480"}]
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TuhHt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(json, function() {     
    console.log(this.title);
});
```

Comment: @digitalbart - This is essentially the same answer as my comment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Do you want to post an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @digitalbart - No, it's ok. We posted it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it just be `$.each(json, function() ... )` ? Your JSON is an array, no wrapper, so just pass it directly to `$.each()`.

Comment: I am not sure what you by passing it directly to $.each()? Can you elaborate

Comment: What both @Sudhir and @Jared show - if your JSON is an array, and you load it into a variable called `json`, just pass `json` as the first argument to `$.each`, rather than passing `json.results`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense I over thought it.